# Адаптивная трапециевидная форма CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, canvas

Я ищу способы для создания адаптивной формы в виде трапеции, которая могут быть реализованы с помощью `CSS`, `SVG` или `Canvas`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я смог создать форму треугольника, но не форму трапеции:

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5vw solid transparent;
  border-left: 10vw solid red;
  border-bottom: 5vw solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Responsive CSS Trapezoid Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33504507/7394871) от участника  [@Stewartside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2889988/stewartside).</sub>

Примечание

*Я выбрал этот простой вопрос-ответ для перевода с Enso, так как здесь собраны практически все возможные способы реализации фигур в виде трапеции. Такие формы могут быть использованы для веб элементов в объемных банерах, меню*

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/33504507/7394871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Существует много разных способов создания формы трапеции, и каждый из них имеет свои преимущества и недостатки.
Ниже в примерах приведен полный список различных способов, и все должны быть адаптивными.

### CSS Border

Этот способ поддерживается в `IE` и во всех других браузерах, как на персональных компьютерах, так и на мобильных устройствах.

[border - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border)

```css
#trapezoid {
  border-left: 20vw solid red;
  border-top: 5vw solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5vw solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

### CSS Perspective

Довольно новый подход в `CSS` - это  метод перспективы в `CSS Transforms`
В настоящее время он достаточно хорошо поддерживается во всех современных браузерах, но может быть довольно сложно получить точный размер формы, который вы хотите.

[perspective - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/perspective)

```css
#trapezoid {
  margin-top: 3vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: red;
  transform: perspective(20vw) rotateY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

### CSS Clip-Path

`Clip-paths` создают клип стиля SVG и это используется  для создания желаемой фигуры.

Это самый простой способ (по крайней мере, на мой взгляд) создать любую форму с простым `CSS`, но не очень хорошо поддерживается даже в современных браузерах.

- [clip-path - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)
- [CanIUse Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)
- [clip-path Generator](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```css
#trapezoid {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 0% 100%);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

### CSS Skew with Pseudo Elements

Способ похож на  ответ с помощью перспективы тем, что он использует `transforms`, но  применяются псевдоэлементы, которые  имеют `skew`.

[skew - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```css
#trapezoid {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 12vw;
  margin: 8vw 0;
}
#trapezoid:before,
#trapezoid:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: skewY(-20deg);
}
#trapezoid:before {
  transform: skewY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

### SVG

`SVG` является масштабируемой векторной графикой. Веб-браузер просматривает его как изображение, но вы можете добавлять текст и обычные элементы `HTML` в `SVG`.

Он хорошо поддерживается во всех браузерах в виде просмотра:

[SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG)

```html
<svg id="trapezoid" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="20%">
  <path d="M0,0
           L100,20
           L100,80
           L0,100z" fill="red"></path>
</svg>
```

### Canvas

Холст похож на SVG, но вместо создания вектора используется растровый (пиксельный) вектор.

Поддержка браузера `Canvas` - [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas)

```js
var shape = document.getElementById('trapezoid').getContext('2d');
shape.fillStyle = 'red';
shape.beginPath();
shape.moveTo(0, 0);
shape.lineTo(100, 20);
shape.lineTo(100, 80);
shape.lineTo(0, 100);
shape.closePath();
shape.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="trapezoid"></canvas>
```

Источник: [Responsive CSS Trapezoid Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33504508/7394871) @Stewartside

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Responsive CSS Trapezoid Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33504508/7394871) от участника  [@Stewartside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2889988/stewartside).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### CSS matrix3d

Хорошая поддержка браузерами - [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=matrix)

```css
.leftDiv{
  margin:1em;
  padding:0.25em;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ccc;
  transform:matrix3d(
  1,0,1,0.003,
  0,1,0,0,
  0,0,1,0,
  0,0,0,1);
} 

.rightDiv{
  margin:1em;
  padding:0.5em;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ccc;
  transform:matrix3d(
  1,0,1,0.004,
  0,1,0,0,
  0,0,1,0,
  0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="leftDiv">This is a skewed shape made by matrix3d</div>
  <h2>testier test</h2>
  <div class="rightDiv">This is a skewed shape made by matrix3d</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я собираюсь добавить недостающий метод из приведенного  [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809305/28748):

### Multiple background & linear-gradient

```css
#trapezoid {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background:
    /* Center area (rectangle)*/
    linear-gradient(red,red) center /100% calc(100% - 40px),
    /* triangle shape at the top*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49%,red 51%) top    / 100% 20px,
    /* triangle shape at the bottom*/
    linear-gradient(to top    left, transparent 49%,red 51%) bottom / 100% 20px;
    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 120px;
    height: 180px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49637870/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>